# How to transfer the information of the token when transmitting RPC communication

Tags: transactions, erc-20, json-rpc, raw-transaction

I have difficulties during the project and ask you questions. Please help me

situation

Create an ERC20-based token and try to create a transaction.
Communication with geth is RPC communication.
How do I send and receive information from the token when communicating with RPC?
question

Create an ERC20 token wallet with the function “personal_newAccoun” t, where you need to put the token information

When sending token, “eth_sendTransaction, eth_sendRawTransaction” should be used to send the token information here

How to load the eth_getBalance token information when checking balance (balance)
“id”: 1 “}” {“jsonrpc”: “2.0”, “method”: “eth_getBalance”, “params”: [“0x502af56ded80f54fac9920010180dcc6f228306d”, “latest”
The above code is an Ethernet balance inquiry. How do I do a token lookup?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use the RPC method `eth_sendRawTransaction` with some encoded data like mention [in the doc](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#eth_sendrawtransaction)